# Select between pickup or delivery shipping methods first in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, shipping-method

I am making website using woocommerce the requirement is that user first select the delivery type either pickup or home delivery on first page then it will go to shop page. if user select pickup on first page then in checkout page I have to give option to choose date and time.

I have created the first page like this

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="postcode" type="text" />
    <button name="shipping" value="delivery" type="submit">Local delivery</button>
    <button name="shipping" value="pickup" type="submit">Local pickup</button>
</form>
```

and in function.php

```
function ff_set_shipping_and_redirect($shipping) {
    WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', array($shipping));
    wp_redirect(site_url('/explore/'));
    exit;
}

function ff_shipping_init() {
    if (isset($_POST['shipping'])) {
        if ($_POST['shipping'] === "pickup") {
            ff_set_shipping_and_redirect('local_pickup');
        } else if ($_POST['shipping'] === "delivery") {

             ff_set_shipping_and_redirect('local_delivery');
          }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'ff_shipping_init');
```

when I am trying to get the selected shiping method on checkout page using this

```
$chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
```

its showing blank array

any body can advice or any better solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

I have lightly changed your form:

```
<?php
// Postcode validation (error message)
if( 'delivery' === WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping') && empty($_POST['postcode']) ) {
    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce"><ul class="woocommerce-error" role="alert"><ul>
        <li><?php _e('The postcode is a required field for "Local delivery"'); ?></li>
    </ul></div>
    <?php
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <label><?php _e("Postcode"); ?><br>
    <input id="input-postcode" name="postcode" type="text" />
    <button name="shipping_type" value="delivery" type="submit"><?php _e("Local delivery"); ?></button>
    <button name="shipping_type" value="pickup" type="submit"><?php _e("Local pickup"); ?></button>
</form>
```

Then the following code will:

- early enable WooCommerce Session for the user (before the first add-to-cart)
- will get the posted data for user shipping choice and inputed postcode
- will warn user when the shipping choice is "delivery" without a postcode
- will set the posted data in WooCommerce Session variables
- will redirect customer to a specific defined page
- will set the real WooCommerce chosen shipping method on Cart and Checkout based on the shipping choice

On the first function you will have to set the correct shipping method rate ID for "Delivery" and "Pickup". You can get them inspecting the shipping methods radio buttons on checkout page (it's the value from name attribute like `name="local_pickup:13"` for example.

The code:

```
// Utility function with your shipping method settings
function get_shipping_rates_id_from_chosen( $chosen_shipping ) { 
    // For "pickup"
    if ( 'pickup' === $chosen_shipping ) {
        return 'local_pickup:13'; // <== Set your "Local pickup" shipping method rate ID
    } 
    // For delivery
    elseif ( 'delivery' === $chosen_shipping ) {
        return 'flat_rate:14'; // <== Set your "Flat rate" shipping method rate ID
    }
}
    
add_action('init', 'set_chosen_shipping_type_to_session');
function set_chosen_shipping_type_to_session() {
    if ( isset($_POST['shipping_type']) ) {
        // Early enable customer WC Session
        if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
            WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
        }
        
        // Get the chosen shipping type
        if ( isset($_POST['shipping_type']) ) {
            // Set chosen shipping type in a session variable
            WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping', wc_clean($_POST['shipping_type']));
        }
        // Get the inputed postcode 
        if ( isset($_POST['postcode']) && ! empty($_POST['postcode']) ) {
            // Set chosen postcode in a session variable
            WC()->session->set('postcode_input', wc_clean($_POST['postcode']) );

            // Set customer shipping postcode
            WC()->customer->set_shipping_postcode( wc_clean($_POST['postcode']) );
        }
    }
}
// redirection after post | Set the chosen shipping method on cart and checkout
add_action('template_redirect', 'action_template_redirect');
function action_template_redirect($shipping) {
    // For "Local delivery" without postcode (no redirection)
    if( isset($_POST['shipping_type']) && 'delivery' === $_POST['shipping_type'] 
    && isset($_POST['postcode']) && empty($_POST['postcode']) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Redirection
    elseif( isset($_POST['shipping_type']) && WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping') ) {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/explore/'));
        exit();
    }
    // Set the chosen shipping method (in cart or checkout)
    elseif( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) ) {
        $chosen_shipping  = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping');
        // Get the 
        $shipping_rate_id = get_shipping_rates_id_from_chosen( $chosen_shipping );
        
        // Set for real the chosen shipping method
        WC()->session->set( 'chosen_shipping_methods', [$shipping_rate_id] );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

For the postcode you can retrieve the value from WC Session variable through:

```
$postcode = WC()->session->get( 'postcode_input' );
```